# MobSF Analyzer failing to work on Gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, sast

I'm trying to set up MobSF SAST within Gitlab-ci and having a few issues.

I've followed the instructions within the [Gitlab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#available-cicd-variables) and within the [MobSF Gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/mobsf)

However, when I add:

To my .gitlab-ci.yml . I get a yml error stating that it could not get access

[image: include: - project: 'gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/mobsf' ref: master file: '/template/mobsf.gitlab-ci.yml']

My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like:

```
sast:
  stage: Security
  tags:
    - docker
include:
      - project: 'gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/mobsf'
        ref: master
        file: '/template/mobsf.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

I have a docker image on my machine with gitlab-runners as an image.  Does anyone have any thoughts about how to implement this so that i can run automated MobSF SAST on both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after working through this, It seems that you must have the following included in yoru gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
  #required for Mobile SAST
  SAST_EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURES: "true"
include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

sast:
  image: docker:19.03.8
  stage: Security
  variables:
    SEARCH_MAX_DEPTH: 4
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json
  tags:
    - docker
```